# Ruby Hash: ordering a hash based on the values (which are arrays of values)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm looking to return a new hash based on the reordering of values in the hash.  The values, themselves, are arrays of ints.

For example:

```
hsh = {"c2" => [44,2], "c1" => [11,33], "c9" => [23,7]}
```

I would like to be able to return a reordered hash based on either value 0 or value 1 in the values.

Any help here is much appreciated - thanks all.

Comment: actually, rails has an ordered hash, and iirc, ruby 1.9 has an ordered hash too...

Comment: Ruby 1.9 remembers the insertion order of the hash, but it doesn't order it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the nature of the question, I assume this is for ruby 1.9.

```
p Hash[hsh.sort_by{|k, v| v[0]}]
# => {"c1"=>[11, 33], "c9"=>[23, 7], "c2"=>[44, 2]}

p Hash[hsh.sort_by{|k, v| v[1]}]
# => {"c2"=>[44, 2], "c9"=>[23, 7], "c1"=>[11, 33]}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for @sawa - thank you.  And yes, this is ruby-1.9.2

Comment: How do you apply sort_by to hash when it's not listed as a method of that class?

Comment: @Jeremy In my case, I do it as usual because I already know how to use it. In your case, you can either (i) ask that as an independent question on Stackoverflow, (ii) look for better documentation, (iii) try to find a documentation more seriously using ri, rdoc, or (iv) just try it with various examples until you can infer how it works.